# Averaging a monthly time series with incomplete observations

Tags: r, database, time-series

I have the following dataset:

```
id observation_date Observation_value
1  2015-02-23       5
1  2015-02-24       6
1  2015-03-01       24
1  2015-07-16       2
1  2015-09-28       9
1  2015-12-05       12
```

I would like to create monthly averages of observation_value. In those cases that there are no values for a certain month, I would like to fill in the data with the average between the months where I have data.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and where you failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data in the Note at the end -- we have added a second id -- convert to zoo using column 1 to split by and column 2 as the index with yearmon class. Also in the same statement aggregate using mean over year/month giving the zoo object z.  Then convert to ts which will fill in the missing months with NA and then convert back to zoo and use na.approx to fill in the NAs (or use na.spline or na.locf depending on what you want).  fortify.zoo(zz) and fortify.zoo(zz, melt = TRUE) can be used to convert zoo objects to data frames.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(dat, FUN = as.yearmon, index = 2, split = 1, aggregate = mean)
zz <- na.approx(as.zoo(as.ts(z)))
```

giving

```
> zz
            1    2
Feb 2015  5.5  5.5
Mar 2015 24.0 24.0
Apr 2015 18.5 18.5
May 2015 13.0 13.0
Jun 2015  7.5  7.5
Jul 2015  2.0  2.0
Aug 2015  5.5  5.5
Sep 2015  9.0  9.0
Oct 2015 10.0 10.0
Nov 2015 11.0 11.0
Dec 2015 12.0 12.0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "id observation_date Observation_value
1  2015-02-23       5
1  2015-02-24       6
1  2015-03-01       24
1  2015-07-16       2
1  2015-09-28       9
1  2015-12-05       12
2  2015-02-23       5
2  2015-02-24       6
2  2015-03-01       24
2  2015-07-16       2
2  2015-09-28       9
2  2015-12-05       12"

dat <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```